# Unable to write to hdd formatted in anything other ext2,3,4

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, filesystems

I am unable to write to my HDD mounted on Ubuntu server 12.04 that are formatted to NTFS or FAT32. However when I format to EXT and Mount as auto its able to write. I tried chmod and chown but the permission stay the same.

Comment: How are you mounting them? Sounds like they are being mounted read-only. Could you show us the relevant lines of your `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: If you give me a few I will be happy to post fstab. But I am mount then using mount -t auto /dev/sdb1 /media/HDD0

Comment: Then we don't need `fstab`. Try `mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb1 /media/HDD0`.

Comment: Weird thing is that 1 of the 3 HDD mounted has rw permission

Comment: Please [edit] your question so it mentions i) that you are mounting manually ii) the output of `mount` when one of the problematic disks is mounted iii) the exact error message you get when you try to write to the disk.

Comment: It is a permissions problem, the fat / ntfs partitions are being mounted owned as root. You have to set ownership and permissions when you mount. The syntax varies with FAT/NTFS, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions#A.3Coption.3E_example